# nginx - rewrite multiple URLs to same location

Tags: nginx

I'm looking to rewrite multiple URLs to the same location. I've done this successfully using mapping, example:

```
map $uri $redirect_to_about {
    ~^/management-team/? 1;
    ~^/about/?   1;
    ~^/tag/?   1;
}

server {
    # ...

    if ($redirect_to_about) {
        return 301 $scheme://$host/about.html;
    }

    # ...
}
```

But an if statement is used, [which is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). So is there a clean, efficient method of rewriting multiple URLs to the same location?

Comment: Your `if` is 100% safe (see your own link), so that's one of the non-evil ones.

Comment: @RichardSmith Are there any performance issues with using if's in the way i've used it?